# Simple Json.Net SelectToken - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Im learning winforms vb.net making an app that gets some exchange rates. Im struggling with json.net (newtonking). My application doesnt break. I can see when debugging that dim `price` is coming out as `nothing` but I cannot figure out why!  :P Can someone help?

Thanks :)

```
    Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Nobody")
    Dim response = client.DownloadString(New Uri("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=131"))
    Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(response)

    Dim price As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("return[0].markets[0].DEM[0].lasttradeprice[0]"))

    Label2.Text = price
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following

```
o.SelectToken("return.markets.DEM.lasttradeprice")
```

In your code you were using `return[0].markets[0].DEM[0].lasttradeprice[0]`, which means, `return`, `markets`, `DEM`, `lasttradeprice` are all array and you were selecting the first element from each array. But in response, `recenttrades`, `sellorders`, `buyorders` are only array. :)

If you are using chrome, Following is a good tool to call web services from browser and get the response as various types.

[**Advanced REST Client**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC)

Answer (score 2):

good tool here to get something working to start from. WOW really good tool! http://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/